# Result sets Java

Tags: java, resultset

I'm creating a program that outputs data from a database into a pie chart and a table. I'm 'trying' to use the model view controller design. My problem is that the result set i am making will have multiple values which i need to extract out, but i don't know how to store them. My code at the moment is:

```
PreparedStatement returnDealerData = con.prepareStatement
    ("SELECT * FROM project.standard_dealer_link WHERE DealerID = "+ this.DealerID +
    "and Quarter =" + this.Quarter + "and Year ="+ this.Year + ";");
    ResultSet dealerRS = returnDealerData.executeQuery();
    while (dealerRS.next()) {
        this.DealerID = dealerRS.getInt("DealerID");
        this.StandardID = dealerRS.getInt("StandardID");
        this.Achieved = dealerRS.getString("Achieved");
        this.NSCWaiver = dealerRS.getString("NSC_Waiver");
        this.Override = dealerRS.getString("Override");
        this.Quarter = dealerRS.getInt("Quarter");
        this.Year = dealerRS.getInt("Year");
    }
```

The data that changes will be StandardID through to Override. So what i need to do is for each iteration i need to store the values somehow so i can then put it into the pie chart and table.
I think what is tripping me up is that i used this method for a result set that only contained one set of values.
any help it much appreciated :).

Comment: Create an object for each row of the result set, and store the objects in a list? Also, please respect the Java naming conventions, and use parameters in your prepared statements rather than string concatenation.

Comment: Okay thankyou, i have only been doing java for a few months, being informally taught by my teacher and we haven't got round to conventions yet. But thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please iterate the values and store each row into the separate data object. So, we need to construct the List of objects.

```
List<DataObject> list = new ArrayList<DataObject>();

while (dealerRS.next()) {
        DataObject obj = new DataObject();
        obj.setDealerID(dealerRS.getInt("DealerID"));
        obj.setStandardID(dealerRS.getInt("StandardID"));
        obj.setAchieved(dealerRS.getString("Achieved"));
        obj.setNSCWaiver(dealerRS.getString("NSC_Waiver"));
        obj.setOverride(dealerRS.getString("Override"));
        obj.setQuarter(dealerRS.getInt("Quarter"));
        obj.setYear(dealerRS.getInt("Year"));
        list.add(obj);
 }
```

Comment: May i ask what the <DataObject> is and how do i use it? i haven't done ArrayLists yet.

Comment: DataObject is user defined object that holds the row data of your table. You are required to define this object

Comment: Okay thankyou! one last thing, what is the procedure to then get the data out?

Comment: Once you have the data in the form the List of objects, then we need to convert this data into user required format. If you are writing simple JSP then you can render the data directly using java iterator. If you are using any scripting language then we need expose a service from the server side and consume on the script side. Please let us know your presentation logic. Based on that i can suggest better way